# How can solve this? trying to create my first react native app and i got the following errors

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

[How can solve this? trying to create my first react native app and i got the following errors
this is what i got]

[the link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RPWD.png)

Comment: Have you setup the environment as the documentation says?

Comment: yes i did all  that

Comment: yes i did all  that